# Show that $g /epsilon $ and $h \ epsilon $ are integrable on $[a,b]$

Tags: integration

Let $\phi$ be a bounded function on $[a, b]$ such that $|\phi(x)| \leq  M$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ for some positive constant $M$, and $\phi$ is integrable on $[a, c]$ for every $c \in (a, b)$.

(i) For sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$, define the functions
$$g_\epsilon(x) =\begin{cases} \phi(x),&  a\leq x \leq b - \epsilon 
\\ -M ,&   b-\epsilon <  x \leq b \end{cases}$$

and
$$h_\epsilon(x) =\begin{cases} \phi(x),&  a\leq x \leq b - \epsilon 
\\ M ,&   b-\epsilon <  x \leq b \end{cases}$$
Show that $g$ and $h$ are integrable on $[a, b]$.

Attempt:
Let $f_\epsilon = g_\epsilon + h_\epsilon = \begin{cases} 2\phi(x),&  a\leq x \leq b - \epsilon 
\\ 0 ,&   b-\epsilon <  x \leq b \end{cases} $

Since it is given that $\phi$ is integrable on $[a,c] $,

Let $\epsilon > 0 $ be given.

There exist a partition $P= $ {$a =x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_n = c$ } where $x_k = a + \frac{c-a}{n} $ for $k =0,1,...,n$

$$U(\phi, P) - L(\phi,P ) < \epsilon $$ by  Riemann integrability criterion.

Then, $$U(2\phi, P) - L(2\phi,P )=2U(\phi, P) - 2L(\phi,P ) < 2\epsilon $$

I am not sure after this. Please advise if I am on the right track.

Comment: We are asked to show that both $g$ and $h$ are integrable.  So, what does one accomplish by adding these?

Comment: Maybe knowing/proving $
\underline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \, dx  = \underline{\int_{a}^{c}} f(x) \, dx +   \underline{\int_{c}^{b}} f(x) \, dx $ and $
\overline{\int_{a}^{b}} f(x) \, dx  = \overline{\int_{a}^{c}} f(x) \, dx +   \overline{\int_{c}^{b}} f(x) \, dx$ 

will help

Comment: $U(f_\epsilon,P) = M $ but $L(f_\epsilon,P) = -M$ ? They are not equal

Comment: @Dr.MV It is proven that if $f$ is integrable, then the sum of $f$ which is $h+g$ is integrable as well.

Comment: That is not what you're asked to show.  You are asked to show that $h$ and $g$ are integrable.